# PhpUnit Wordpress Error install-wp-tests.sh

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I am running the script from Cygwin and I get the following error

```
bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root 'my_pass' localhost latest
```

Result:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to s'
```

This is the line where the error occurs and the execution ends

```
sed $ioption "s:dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/':'$WP_CORE_DIR/':" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
```

Why does this error occur?

regards

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this error occur?

First of all [*Integrating WP Unit Testing in Windows*](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/misc/plugin-unit-tests/#integrating-wp-unit-testing-in-windows) outlines a couple of reasons already.

If you ask *why* because you're looking for a solution, there is this on the page:

> Lastly, sometimes the bash script fails to build WordPress because of how it uses tmp folders. If it fails, then you can manually install WordPress to a writeable directory, and then manually create wp-tests-config.php.

---

Here is a bit of background:

Most likely there is a colon ("`:`") in the *directory name* or in `$WP_CORE_DIR` (and as it is not encoded for the sed-pattern) sed sees it at the end of the `s:<search>:<replace>:<option>...` search expression and stumbles over the unintended option which then is unknown - and tells you.

On *nix systems a colon is *normally* not part of a pathname. which means, that you've run into an incompatibility with that shell script with your system. It is not portable with cygwin.

You can either try to make the script portable with cygwin, e.g. by quoting the colons for `<search>` and `<replace>` (see `sed(1)` for sed expression syntax).

Or you can read the sed expression (again see `sed(1)`) and apply the changes to the test wordpress-configuration-file manually your own (this is the suggestion from the manual, so probably the first way to go with).